# how to solve name is not defined issue in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here][1][How can I solve name is not defined issue, I am using python 3.6.5. I have tried using the global and many more techniques

here'my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except ImportError:
    print('Requested Driver Not Found')
except RuntimeError:
    print('Driver fails to initialize')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

for voice in voices:
    print(voice.id)
```

And the issue

```
"E:\Python projects\Dizzi\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "E:/Python projects/Dizzi/Dizzi.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
Requested Driver Not Found
  File "E:/Python projects/Dizzi/Dizzi.py", line 12, in <module>
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
NameError: name 'engine' is not defined
```

][2]

Answer (score 0):

pyttsx3.init() is failed,*Requested Driver is not Founded*.
the variable **engine** isn’t created.

You should check is there has any import error.

Comment: No, I haven't found any error while importing files